# Show component and Edit component use the same record of List Component?

Tags: admin-on-rest

Why is `record` of `Show` and `Edit` component the same as `record` of `List` Component?

Comment: What should it be?

Comment: The response data of the request sent by rest client when you click an Edit button or Show button?

Comment: The record in AOR is the data will be displayed when the page loads next and it is fetched from the state. AOR also has optimistic rendering which means they don't wait for server response to show changes made to state. If you need to show the server response then you can look at one of my long answers about showing server response. It is longish task currently though.

Comment: Fine. Thanks for your clarifications!